# How to implement the Gaussian one factor model for Short rate

Tags: swaps, quantlib, interest-rate-swap

I am struggling to understand how I should use the **Gaussian one factor model** for short rate for valuation of a `Swaption`. Below is my `Swaption` parameters -

```
from QuantLib import *
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
calc_date = Date(29, 3, 2019)
start = 10
length = 10
start_date =  TARGET().advance(calc_date, start, Years)
maturity_date = start_date + Period(length, Years)

spot_curve = FlatForward(calc_date, QuoteHandle(SimpleQuote(0.01)), Actual365Fixed())
termStructure = YieldTermStructureHandle(spot_curve)
index = Euribor6M(termStructure)

fixedSchedule = Schedule(start_date,     ## pd.DataFrame({'date': list(fixedSchedule)})
                         maturity_date, 
                         Period(1, Years),  
                         TARGET(), 
                         Unadjusted,  
                         Unadjusted, 
                         DateGeneration.Forward,  
                         False
                    )
floatingSchedule = Schedule(start_date,  ## pd.DataFrame({'date': list(floatingSchedule)})
                            maturity_date, 
                            Period(6, Months),  
                            TARGET(), 
                            ModifiedFollowing,  
                            ModifiedFollowing, 
                            DateGeneration.Forward,  
                            True
                         )

forward = VanillaSwap(VanillaSwap.Receiver,  
                      10000000, 
                      fixedSchedule,  
                      1.45 / 100,
                      Thirty360(Thirty360.BondBasis), 
                      floatingSchedule,  
                      index,  
                      0.0, 
                      index.dayCounter()
                    )
swap = forward

exercise = start_date
exercised = EuropeanExercise(exercise)
settlementtype = "physical"
atmswaption = Swaption(swap, exercised)
vol1  = QuoteHandle(SimpleQuote(0.005266))
```

Now I use the `Gaussian1dSwaptionEngine` to value the Swaption as below -

```
atmswaption.setPricingEngine(Gaussian1dSwaptionEngine(Vasicek(0.05, 0.1, 0.05, 0.01, 0.0),
                                                      64,              
                                                      7.0,             
                                                      True,           
                                                      False,           
                                                      termStructure    
                                                      
                                                    )); print(atmswaption.NPV())
```

With this I am getting below error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
  File "/Users/aaa/ql-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/QuantLib/QuantLib.py", line 21358, in __init__
    _QuantLib.Gaussian1dSwaptionEngine_swiginit(self, _QuantLib.new_Gaussian1dSwaptionEngine(*args))
TypeError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_Gaussian1dSwaptionEngine'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    Gaussian1dSwaptionEngine::Gaussian1dSwaptionEngine(boost::shared_ptr< Gaussian1dModel > const &,int const,Real const,bool const,bool const,Handle< YieldTermStructure > const &,Gaussian1dSwaptionEngine::Probabilities const)
    Gaussian1dSwaptionEngine::Gaussian1dSwaptionEngine(boost::shared_ptr< Gaussian1dModel > const &,int const,Real const,bool const,bool const,Handle< YieldTermStructure > const &)
    Gaussian1dSwaptionEngine::Gaussian1dSwaptionEngine(boost::shared_ptr< Gaussian1dModel > const &,int const,Real const,bool const,bool const)
    Gaussian1dSwaptionEngine::Gaussian1dSwaptionEngine(boost::shared_ptr< Gaussian1dModel > const &,int const,Real const,bool const)
    Gaussian1dSwaptionEngine::Gaussian1dSwaptionEngine(boost::shared_ptr< Gaussian1dModel > const &,int const,Real const)
    Gaussian1dSwaptionEngine::Gaussian1dSwaptionEngine(boost::shared_ptr< Gaussian1dModel > const &,int const)
    Gaussian1dSwaptionEngine::Gaussian1dSwaptionEngine(boost::shared_ptr< Gaussian1dModel > const &)
```

Could you please help me to understand why am I getting this error?

I also failed to understand the meaning of the parameters passed to the `Gaussian1dSwaptionEngine` -

*1. integrationPoints

2. stddevs
3. extrapolatePayoff
4. flatPayoffExtrapolation
5. probabilities*

Your pointer is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is caused because the class `Gaussian1dSwaptionEngine` expects a model of the parent class `Gaussian1dModel`, which `Vasicek` is not.

This snippet gives an example of defining a GSR model, which is accepted by your engine:

```
volStepDates = [Date(1, 1, 2020)]
volatilities = [vol1, vol1]
reversions = [QuoteHandle(SimpleQuote(0.01)), QuoteHandle(SimpleQuote(0.01))]

gsr = Gsr(termStructure, volStepDates, volatilities, reversions)

engine = Gaussian1dSwaptionEngine(gsr, 64, 7.0, True, False, termStructure)

atmswaption.setPricingEngine(engine)
print(atmswaption.NPV())
```

You can read mode about the GSR model [here](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2246013) (paper) or [here](https://deriscope.com/products/GSR_Model.html) (high level view with links) - in the snippet above I've entered holding parameters but you should think about how you would like to parameterise your model.

Comment: Thanks. In "Gaussian1dSwaptionEngine" function, you input various parameters as "(64, 7.0, True, False)". Could you please help understanding these parameters?

Comment: https://rkapl123.github.io/QLAnnotatedSource/d2/db3/class_quant_lib_1_1_gaussian1d_swaption_engine.html#details <-- defined here, `integrationPoints` and `stddevs` control the gridding that is used by the pricer (line 54 here https://rkapl123.github.io/QLAnnotatedSource/d0/db9/gaussian1dswaptionengine_8cpp_source.html), the remaining two `extrapolatePayoff` and `flatPayoffExtrapolation` control the extrapolations outside of these ranges

Comment: Thanks. However I am aware of this file. What I could not understand is the underlying mathematical model to setup such grid and purpose thereof. Do you have any information on the technical article/resources to explain them?